# Special icon characters  in Android Studio

Tags: xcode, android-studio, unicode

In xcode it's possible to have characters like "" in code. If I paste it to Android Studio it shows me another 2 unicode characters, which don't have anything in common with "".

Both editors use UTF-8 encoding AFAIK.

So where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`Android Studio` uses `windows-1252` as default and you can use the unicode equivalent:

```
\uD83D\uDC8A
```

for example using a `TextView`:

```
myTextView.setText("\uD83D\uDC8A");
```

will create something like (in my device two pills are showed):

[image]

Here you can find the equivalent "Java Escape" code :

http://www.charbase.com/1f48a-unicode-pill

Comment: But why does Android Studio tell me that is using UTF-8 then? see bar at the very bottom right.

Comment: Yes, the project encoding default is windows-1252 but you can change (Convert) to UTF-8.In fact i use the default encoding.

Comment: I have changed my Android Studio project from windows-1252 to UTF-8 and can display with no problem the pill. :)